# How to store spacy doc objects and reload them correctly?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a about 90 documents that i have processed with spacy.

```
import spacy, os

nlp = spacy.load('de')
index = 1
for document in doc_collection:
    doc = nlp(document)
    doc.to_disk('doc_folder/' + str(index))
```

It seems to be working fine. After that i want to reload the doc files later as a generator object.

```
def get_spacy_doc_list():
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)

        yield spacy.tokens.Doc(spacy.vocab.Vocab()).from_disk('doc_folder/' + filename)


for doc in get_spacy_doc_list():
    for token in doc:
        print(token.lemma_)
```

If I try this, then i get the following error:

```
KeyError: "[E018] Can't retrieve string for hash '12397158900972795331'."
```

How i can store and load the doc objects of spacy without getting this error?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
yield spacy.tokens.Doc(spacy.vocab.Vocab()).from_disk('doc_folder/' + filename)
```

The Vocab()-instance should be the specific one of your nlp.

```
yield spacy.tokens.Doc(nlp.vocab).from_disk('doc_folder/' + filename)
```

Comment: To add to your answer: You can also serialize the `Vocab` separately by calling its [`to_disk()` method](https://spacy.io/api/vocab#to_disk). This is especially useful if you've added to it or modified it. (You'll only have to do this once for all `Doc` objects that share the same vocab.)